# Silverlight: Using DataContextProxy to access ObserableCollection elements

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to get binding working in the header of a grid column which does not have access to the DataContext. To give it access, I used the DataContextProxy described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx

This is a simplified version of my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private String _myString;
 private ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> _tabItems;

 public String MyString { blah... }
 public ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> TabItems {blah... }
}
```

and it works for accessing the MyString using XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource.MyString}"/>
```

but I'm not sure how to get it to point at the ErrorHeading inside the observable collection of TabItemViewModels...

```
public class TabItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private string _errorHeading;

 public string ErrorHeading
    {
        get { return _errorHeading; }
        set
        {
            _errorHeading = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorHeading");
        }
    }



}
```

I tried it like this:

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource.TabItems.ErrorHeading}"/>
```

but I dont think you can dig into the ObservableCollection like this - I'm not even sure how it knows which element in the collection to look at.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TabItemViewModel` implementation, you've defined `ErrorHeading` two times.

At one place you write

```
 RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorHeading");
```

while another place you've written

```
 OnPropertyChanged("ErrorHeading");
```

Looks like there is some serious problem with your code. On the top of it, you've not implemented the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `TabItemViewModel`.

So fix these problems first. Maybe, then you would be able to do something more elegant in your code. :-)

Comment: Sorry mate, that was just a copy paste error, this is my first time using the stackoverflow site. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, but left it out for brevity.